# Get TreeView of files with special extension

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to create a tree view that will list of files that end with special `extension` , lets stay `".txt"`

example :

```
root
    folder1
           f.txt
           f1.wml
           f2.exe
    folder2
           f3.exe
    folder3
           ...
           ...
    folder4
           f4.txt
           f5.txt
```

---> results should be

```
root
    folder1
           f.txt
    folder4
           f4.txt
           f5.txt
```

What I have so far:

```
public TreeNode DirectoryToTreeView (string path, string extension = ".txt")
{
  //TreeNode NewTreeNode = new TreeNode(path);
  var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
  var rootDirectory = new  System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
  var NewTreeNode = new TreeNode(rootDirectory.FullName) { Tag = rootDirectory };
  stack.Push(NewTreeNode);

  while (stack.Count > 0)
  {
    var currentNode = stack.Pop();
    var directoryInfo = (System.IO.DirectoryInfo)currentNode.Tag;
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
      var childDirectoryNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name) { Tag = directory };
      currentNode.Nodes.Add(childDirectoryNode);
      stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);
    }
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
      if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension( file.Name) == extension)
        currentNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
  }
  return NewTreeNode;
}
```

Later I'll use this method as

```
TreeNode NewNode = DirectoryToTreeView(TreeRootDir); 
MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(NewNode);
```

This function will end up giving me a tree of all directories, and within only files that end up with `".txt"`

What do I need to do to remove directories that are empty of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out any directory nodes that don't have any child nodes.  I think your `Stack<TreeNode>` version complicates that, so I replaced it with a recursive version:

```
private TreeNode DirectoryToTreeView(TreeNode parentNode, string path,
                                     string extension = ".txt") {
  var result = new TreeNode(parentNode == null ? path : Path.GetFileName(path));
  foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {
    TreeNode node = DirectoryToTreeView(result, dir);
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0) {
      result.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
  }
  foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
    if (Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower() == extension.ToLower()) {
      result.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You just call it with a null parent:

```
MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(DirectoryToTreeView(null, @"c:\temp"));
```

Comment: Works Great !! 
How did come up with this solution ?